# Should I use resource files for application modes?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, resx

**TL;DR**

Are resource files just for language translations, or can they be used for other variables?

---

I have an application which will be deployed onto multiple servers with different configuration settings for each.

For example my configuration has:

```
<add key="AppMode" value="CompanyA"/>
```

At the moment I do something like:

```
@{
  string companyName;  
  switch(AppMode){
     case: "CompanyA":
        companyName= "Company A";
        break;
     case: "CompanyB":
        companyName= "Company B";
        break;
     case: "CompanyC":
        companyName= "Company C";
        break;
  }
}

<h1>@companyName</h1>
```

This sort of logic is littered across the application for various things. Site Logo path etc..

In the past I've used Localization `.resx` files to store different translations.

Can/Should I use `.resx` files for different application modes?

For example I could have:

- Resources.companya.resx
- Resources.companyb.resx
- Resources.companyc.resx

Is this an acceptable, best practice, use of `.resx` files, or are they purely for languages?

Comment: I am not sure if I am answering your question. Why not creating new key in web.config that stores the Company Name?

Comment: @Hatjhie That was just one example. Imagine I have 100's of differences.

Comment: @Hatjhie I'd rather have 1 config setting which controls which set of data to use. Having 100's of individual config settings would be difficult to maintain.

Comment: Understood. You might want to take a look on this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231476/are-resx-files-a-suitable-way-to-customise-for-different-customers