# Branding a wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, branding, white-labelling

I'm developing a "white label" WPF application, ie an application that will be resold under different brands. This means I need to be able to change text content, icons, etc easily. How is this best implemented in WPF? I've been putting texts and icons for my "unbranded" development look into a resource file, is this the way to go? I have seen suggestions ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635390/how-to-load-different-resx-files-based-on-some-parameter)) to then append the brand name to the culture (something like Resourcefile.en-US-Brand1.resx), but this seems like a hack to me, requiring custom cultures etc.

As an additional constraint, I cannot ship all brandings (different vendors cannot be associated with each other by inspecting assemblies), so I think I need to put this into different files and then select the correct one when packing the application?

What are my options? I've been searching a bit, but there isn't much information on this.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion would be a Content management system which would be a web application. The url, username, passwords to log into the CMS will be for your client. They will upload the images, text, description, etc on this individually for individual "white label". You need to pull these from the server (using a web service or something) and load it dynamically in your WPF application.

I know this is a very short description and a decent bit of development work but it is very easy to maintain when there are any changes coming from the client.

A product for CMS given by Microsoft .net is [DotNetNuke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DotNetNuke)

Hope this gives you some direction.